# Elastic search query string to term query

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got the following `elastic search (0.90)` query which return hits based on the `id` field with combinations of `OR` operator between them. It's working perfectly.

```
$query = '{
    "fields": "position",
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "id:rs6663158 id:rs6695131",
            "default_operator": "OR"
        }
    }
}';
```

I wish to do the same with a much simpler query and I found the `term` option and I have the following which is working fine:

```
$query = '{
    "fields": "position",
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "id": "rs6663158",
            "default_operator": "OR"
        }
    }
}';
```

I'm not sure how to add more than 1 `id` field like: `"id": ["rs6663158", "rs7221234"]`. Is it possible to do this with `term` option, if not is there any other better and simpler solution?

Comment: You can use the [`terms`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/query-dsl-terms-filter.html) filter for multiple values to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `terms` query, like this

```
$query = '{
    "fields": "position",
    "query": {
        "terms": {
            "id": ["rs6663158", "rs6695131"]
        }
    }
}';
```